# INSERT query actually didn't insert any data

Tags: c#, mysql-workbench

Currently, I'm working on a project for a shop. The problem I encountered is that the "INSERT" query didn't actually insert anything.

The `try-catch` didn't find anything wrong, which is adding my confusion. I have also debugged the code and found nothing abnormal.

```
koneksi.Open();             
MySqlCommand masuk = new MySqlCommand(a, koneksi);
masuk.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

Random utk_id = new Random();
int panggil_acak = utk_id.Next();

masuk.Parameters.AddWithValue("_id_transaksi", Convert.ToString(panggil_acak));
masuk.Parameters.AddWithValue("_id_barang", Convert.ToString(id.Text));
masuk.Parameters.AddWithValue("_nama_barang", Convert.ToString(nama.Text));
masuk.Parameters.AddWithValue("_harga_satuan", Convert.ToString(harga.Text));
masuk.Parameters.AddWithValue("_jumlah_barang", Convert.ToString(jmlh_brg_beli.Text));
masuk.Parameters.AddWithValue("_diskon", Convert.ToString(diskon_rp.Text));
masuk.Parameters.AddWithValue("_harga_total", Convert.ToString(harga_barang_total.Text));
masuk.Parameters.AddWithValue("_tgl_transaksi", Convert.ToString(DateTime.Now.ToString()));

//execute command
masuk.ExecuteNonQuery();
clear text area and refresh data grid
rstArea();
isiDgrid();
```

the command is a stored procedure and the application gives no error feedback.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `belanjaTemp_add`(
_id_transaksi varchar(20),
_id_barang varchar(10),
_nama_barang varchar(255),
_harga_satuan varchar(10),
_jumlah_barang varchar(10),
_diskon varchar(45),
_harga_total varchar(10),
_tgl_transaksi varchar(45)
)
BEGIN
if(_id_transaksi = 0)
then
insert into komodo.penjualan_temp
(id_transaksi, id_barang, nama_barang, harga_satuan, jumlah_barang, diskon, harga_total, tgl_transaksi)
values
(_id_transaksi, _id_barang, _nama_barang, _harga_satuan, _jumlah_barang, _diskon, _harga_total, _tgl_transaksi);
END if;
END
```

I expected the database will be updated but it's not updated. 
The screenshot for succeed confirmation :
https://ibb.co/b26YdBY

My question : how do I manage to get the data inserted?

Comment: Please don't post links to outside code you need help with, please update your post to include this information. I would assume you are successful in connecting to the database correct?

Comment: Can you execute the query outside of the code? If not, then the issue is with the query.

Comment: @codexer : db connection is successful

Comment: @JohnPete22 : i can execute it outside the code

Comment: Okay, so it might be the code then.  Does the user for the database have permissions to update data, not just read?

Comment: @JohnPete22: the user have full permission to add/update/delete data

Comment: It looks like your stored proc is only inserting, not updating data.  And only if ````_id_transaksi = 0```` is true.  Silly question, but are you not seeing any new data because that logic condition isn't met?

Comment: Also, shouldn't the ````_id_transaksi = 0```` be looking at ````_id_transaksi = '0'```` since the field is ````varchar(20)```` ?  I'm not too familiar with MySql (thought this was a C# issue), but I know in SQL Server this would be an issue.

Comment: @JohnPete22 : problem solved! logic error, yup, my bad.. thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try using `ExecuteStoredProcedure()` instead of `ExecuteNonQuery()`;

Comment: `ExecuteNonQuery` is fine as long as you specify the command to be `CommandType.StoredProcedure`.